# Windows Azure - My management certificate has no thumbprint, why?

Tags: azure

Looking in the Hosted Services, Storage Accounts & CDN, under Management Certificates, I see my one Subscription and the Subscription ID, but the Thumbprint is blank.  I need the thumbprint in order to upload my VHD.  Why is it missing?  What do I need to do to get it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you specifically created a management certificate? If not the easiest way to do it is to use the [Visual Studio Azure SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27577) and from in there go as if you were deploying an application. It will walk you through the steps for adding a management certificate. Alternatively you should be able to find more information from [this blog post](http://www.davidaiken.com/2009/12/21/how-to-create-a-x509-certificate-for-the-windows-azure-management-api/).